# Elasticsearch the different score between term and terms

Tags: elasticsearch

my request like this
term:

```
{
    "from":0,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"term":{
                    "type_id":{
                        "value" : 34
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":20
}
```

term

```
{
    "from":0,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"terms":{"type_id":[34]}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":20
}
```

there are 67 docs in this index
`term` query return score is 0.0149 every doc
but `terms` query return score is 1.0 ever doc

`term` score seems is  1/67

and after I add another type_id 35, 2016 docs in index
`term` score is 3.4299169
`terms` score still is 1.0

I want terms and term perform the same.
And want to know how is it working ?
Thanks

Comment: what is data type of type_id?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal   it's keyword

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/whats-the-difference-between-terms-and-term-with-bool-should/285186) has more discussion

> Terms queries do not score matches based on IDF (the rareness) of
> matched terms - the term query does.

If you will run both queries using ?explain=true.
You will see term query calculates score based while terms applies constantScore

**Term Query**

```
GET index62/_search?explain=true
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type_id.keyword": {
              "value": "35"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

**Result**

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.4700036,
          "description" : "weight(type_id.keyword:35 in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details" : [
            {
         "value" : 0.4700036,
              "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 2.2,
                  "description" : "boost",
                  "details" : [ ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.47000363,
                  "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2,
                      "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 3,
                      "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.45454544,
                  "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                     "value" : 1.2,
                      "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.75,
                      "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "dl, length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

**Terms Query**

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "type_id.keyword": [
              "35"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

**Result**

```
"_explanation" : 
{
      "value" : 1.0,
      "description" : "ConstantScore(type_id.keyword:35)",
      "details" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for late response . Thanks for your kindle reponse . I have got it .

Comment: If I have type_id `34`  , `35`, `36` . But if want to use `term` to add boost in `34` , the result seems not accurate . Because thought `34` boost is `2`, also maybe lower than `35` or `36` when other clause  and doc content is the same . If don't want to use `terms` , is there any method to do ?

Comment: @xrui , with boost 34 should appear on top. Can you add your query in question and a  sample doc for 34 and 35 to see what is affecting the score. Explanation api can also tell why certain doc is scored more

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was really not expecting `terms` to work differently than `term`. This is kinda dumb.